# User.insertOne() buffered after 10000 ms

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model, schema

Anna connected to online mongodb atlas. It works fine. But when I create a user in users model, it shows user.insertone buffered after 10000ms.Many people in the internet said . It is the problem in the connection.

In the network access I gave access to all ip address. And also downgraded mongoose version to 5.something. Nothing works

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).